# How to fetch data from jsp page while calling it from a java servlet/application?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to send book title to a jsp page and i want it to supply me the price of tht book..is it possible???and I have to call the jsp page from a java application or servlet.

So the entire process is...

user gives title of book, the books title is sent to a jsp page in localhost which send the price to the java application which is relayed to the client gui...

Comment: what is the code that you have tried

Comment: Learn JSP/Servlet by book/tutorial first and apply the lessons learnt. This is a too generic question. Come back when you have a more specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a simple Java web application. Try using [appfuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home) to establish a simple skeleton and add the required features.